# Fill value in NETCDF in R

Tags: r, na, fill, netcdf

I want R to know that this stack NetCDF contains a value -1e30 which is a fill value and it's a NA. Since the other actual values are quite similar to the NA value (1e17 to -4e18).R should understand that -1e30 is an NA and skips NA in further analysis for code `na.rm=TRUE`. 
I am working on list of files in NetCDF DATA https://drive.google.com/open?id=14OX9JAe7oZ7xPRuIzR7YB2P3OHC3zjJU

```
> ras <- list.files("filepath", pattern = "\\.nc$", full=TRUE)
> Data <- stack(ras)
> u2 <- mean(Data, na.rm=TRUE).
```

How do I write the code?

```
> NA<- -1e30
> Mean <-mean(Data,na.rm=TRUE)
```

or

```
> Data[Data < -1e30] = NA
> Mean <-mean(Data,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Will this code make R understand that -1e30 is an NA in the dataset and skip the -1e30 in taking out mean?

```
> dput(Data[1:100, 1:100])
NaN, 4748499736330240, NA, NA, NA, -2119029758099456, -1656679481475072, 3074375171440640, 2699225347391488, 1389911546527744, 3767667181748224,..
```

Comment: I see there are two types (NA and NAN). What does it mean? why two NA and NAN?

Comment: do you check if you have `NAN` in the raw .nc file?

Comment: How to check?    Only thing i see is fill value in the file header as 1e30 and ```> dput(r1[1:100, 1:100])``` for one .nc file is giving ```NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,```

Comment: you can try my answer which turns `NAN` and `-1e30` to `NA`

Answer (score 2):

You have a vector

```
a <- c(1,2,3,1e30)
```

You need to replace the values in there:

```
a <- ifelse(a == 1e30, NA, a)
```

Comment: I am working on list of files in NetCDF ```ras <- list.files("filepath", pattern = "\\.tif$", full=TRUE)
Data <- stack(ras)
u2 <- mean(Data, na.rm=TRUE)```   So, if i use ```u3 <- ifelse(u2 == -1e30, NA, u2)``` it's giving me "Error in which(test) : argument to 'which' is not logical"

Comment: OK, this is unclear to me. Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Edited the question with a reproducible example. Kinldy look into it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should used `|` for condition in `ifelse()`

```
r <- mean(ifelse(Data < -1e30 | is.nan(Data), NA, Data),na.rm = T)
```

**Example with dummy data**

```
Data <- c(NaN, 4748499736330240, NA, NA, NA, -2119029758099456, -1656679481475072, 3074375171440640, 2699225347391488, 1389911546527744, 3767667181748224, -1e31)
r <- mean(ifelse(Data < -1e30 | is.nan(Data), NA, Data),na.rm = T)
```

such that

```
> r
[1] 1.700567e+15
```

where

```
> ifelse(Data < -1e30 | is.nan(Data), NA, Data)
 [1]            NA  4.748500e+15            NA            NA
 [5]            NA -2.119030e+15 -1.656679e+15  3.074375e+15
 [9]  2.699225e+15  1.389912e+15  3.767667e+15            NA
```

Comment: Data in the script is a stack of NetCDF files. When i use ```> r2 <- mean(ifelse(Data< -1e30 | is.nan(Data), NA, Data),na.rm = T)``` i get error 
```Error in which(test) : argument to 'which' is not logical```

Comment: @Dipu can you paste the complete `dput(Data)` to your post?

Comment: Dimension is 1800 3600 (huge) so I am attaching the ```dput(Data)``` in a document in the link with name "dput".

Comment: can you copy `dput(Data)` to a .txt in your google drive? I am not able to run your files

Comment: i did.please check...You can run it using my code in the text file. use that

Comment: updated the link with data, codes, and ouputs (results) . please check and let me know

Comment: @Dipu `dput()` will give the something like `structure(....)`, why yours does not in the dput1.txt file?

Comment: i have no idea about that.

Comment: @Dipu you don't need `d <- dput(Data)`, you just do `dput(Data)` and then copy the output in the console

Comment: check the other text 'dput.txt'. That is the ```dput(Data)``` ouput. Since Data is a stack ```dput(Data)``` is returning that output and not ```structure(...)```

Comment: @Dipu I have no idea how to proceed with your dput()....sorry

Comment: it's okay. At least you tried to help me. Thanks a lot for your time